# X uniformly distributed, is X and X to the power of n got correlation or not

Tags: probability

Basically I got this question where:
$X$~$U[-C,C]$ where C is natural > 1.
And the question that asks, name the correct answer:

1. $X$ and $X^2$ are independent
2. $X$ and $X^7$ are uncorrelated
3. $X^5$ and $X^6$ are uncorrelated

And I got an option for "none of above are true".

How to approach this kind of questions? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: 1) Please use mathjax. 2) What has $N$ to do with your question? 3) Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Stockfish hi, thanks, I used mathjax, I have no idea how to start and this is what I ask, how to approach. Regarding the N is C I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $X^{n}$ are independent for some $n >1$ then any mesurable function of $X$ is also independent of $X^{n}$ so $X^{n}$ is independent of itself. This implies that $X^{n}$ is a constant. Obviously this is not true. So 1) and 2) are false.If 3) is true then  $X^{30}$  would be independent of itself.

Comment: I see, let me think for a few minutes

Comment: Thank you Kavi, I understand.

Comment: @AvielFedida For 2) and 3) you can also compute the Covariance to check if the correlation is 0. For 1), search for intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$ such that $P(X \in I_1, X^2 \in I_2) \neq P(X \in I_1) P(X^2 \in I_2)$.

Comment: Just to make sure, its "none of above are true" and I can as @Stockfish actually calculate it to check right?

Comment: @AvielFedida "None of the above " is the answer. You can follow the advice of Stockfish but it is not necessary  to produce $I_1$ and $I_2$. My argument is good enough.